# Find all solutions to expression for $w\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Wish to find all solutions to:
$$
w(\operatorname{Log}(w)+2n \pi i)^2=1
$$
for $w\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.  I believe there are no solutions.  My first attempt was to let $w=re^{it}$ and expand into real and imaginary parts but that's still an underdetermined system because of $n$ and also the resulting expressions are quite messy.   I can prove it is false for $w\in\mathbb{R}$ easily.
I was wondering if someone could suggest another approach to this problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Technically, $Log$ denotes the principal branch of $\log$, so $Log(w)+2n\pi i=\log_n(w)$ (the multivalued $\log_n$), so set $z_n=\log_n(w)$ and write your equation as: $z_n^2\exp(z_n)=1$, which can be solved via the Lambert $W$ function, as: $z_n=2W(1/2)$ or $z_n=2W(-1/2)$. Then, since $z_n=Log(w)+2n\pi i$, solve for $w$ the last set of the two equations and exclude the $n$ you want.

Comment: Very nice Yiannis.  Initially it seems if $w=\text{exp}(2W(n,-1/2)$, then $w[\text{Log}(w)+4n\pi i]^2=1$.  Will work more with it.

Comment: also, don't forget that the two solutions $W(1/2)$ and $W(-1/2)$ are actually two sets of infinitely many solutions. All the solutions then are really determined by $2W_k(1/2)$ and $W_k(-1/2)$, so you may need to adjust your indexes to take this into account, as $z_{n,k}=2W_k(1/2)$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, etc. Then, list all solutions according to your indexes, $k$ and $n$.

Comment: I'm wondering if $\text{exp}(2W(n,1/2))$ may be a spurious solution from the square root as I am initially unable to obtain the equality $w[\text{Log}(w)+2n\pi i]^2=1$ using this value although I've only looked at it just a bit as yet.

Comment: The final answer may include some duplicates, since $\exp$ is periodic, but spurious? I don't think so. Try to work all the solutions using both indexes $n$ and $k$ and see what you get. Don't confuse the two indexes - they are independent. If you can't see it, ping me to post a complete answer.

Comment: Ok, if $w=\text{exp}(2W(k,1/2))$, then $w[\text{Log}(w)+2(2k-1)\pi i]^2=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log}$

Here's my take on it, so you can check your set of solutions against it (comment space is too short for verification).

As I said in the comments, set: $\Log(w)+2n\pi i=\log_n(w)$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (which is the definition of the multivalued complex log map, anyway - with $\Log$ denoting the principal branch). The original equation transforms to $w(\log_n(w))^2=1\Leftrightarrow (\log_n(w))^2\exp(\log_n(w))=1$. This is solved by $W$ as: $\log_n(w)=2W_k(\pm 1/2)$.

So we have: $w=w_{n,k}=\exp(\log_n(w))=\exp(2W_k(\pm 1/2)), k\in \mathbb{Z}. \tag 1$

Now, if $w$ is given as above, it's easy to check that these satisfy the original equation:

\begin{align}
& w(\Log(w)+2n\pi i)^2=w(\log_n(w))^2=\exp(\log_n(w))(\log_n(w))^2 \\[6pt]
= {} & \exp(2W_k(\pm 1/2))(2W_k(\pm 1/2))^2=4\cdot \exp(M)\cdot M\cdot \exp(M)\cdot M,
\end{align}

with $M=W_k(\pm 1/2)$. Using the definition of $W_k$, the last expression evaluates to $4\cdot (\pm1/2)\cdot(\pm1/2)=1$.

More formally speaking, using indexes, pick $w_k=2W_k(\pm 1/2)$. Then, $w_k(\Log(w_k)+2n\pi i)^2$, which is:
$w_k(\log_n(w_k)-2n\pi i+2n\pi i)^2$, or: $w_k(\log_n(w_k))^2=\exp(\log_n(w_k))(\log_n(w_k))^2$, or:
$\exp(2W_k(\pm 1/2))(2W_k(\pm1/2))^2$, which is: $=4\cdot \exp(M)\cdot M\cdot \exp(M)\cdot M=1$, as above.

**Note**: Technically speaking, the correct notation for the roots should be $w_{n,k}$ on $(1)$, as the two indexes are independent and $\Log(w)=\log_n(w)-2n\pi i$, so the solutions should have resolved as: $w_{n,k}=\exp(\log_n(w)-2n\pi i)=\exp(2W_k(\pm 1/2)-2n\pi i)$. One first **fixes** $n$ in the original equation and then picks up solutions. Fortunatelly, the $n$ index collapses because of the periodicity of $\exp$ and the above resolves to just $w_k=\exp(2W_k(\pm 1/2))$, so the solution set depends only on the index $k$ of $W$. So the total number of solutions is indexed by $\{1,2\}\times\mathbb{Z}$ ($\pm$ groups).